# Java SWT Image and Transparency

Tags: image, swt, transparent

I need to create an image with layers. The bottom layer - png-image without transparency, the top - transparent png image.
GUI on SWT. I am used GC class for drawing on Image, which is the result. After that, I am set Image-object in the Canvas. The problem is that when drawing the transparency is lost. How to keep transparency and to implement what I need?

Comment: What about giving a [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/)?